# Share multiple segment with QSharedMemory

Tags: qt, shared, segment

i want to use QSharedMemory to share data between 2 applications using it for sharing one segment works perfectly but when i try 2 share more than one i have access just to the last one

this my code

sharedMemroy.cpp in the first application

```
void SharedMemory::loadIntoSharedMem(QString memoryKey,QString &data)
    {
    sharedMem.setKey(memoryKey);
    if (sharedMem.isAttached())
        {
        sharedMem.detach();
        }
    if( data.length())
        {
    // load into shared memory
         QBuffer buffer;
         buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadWrite);
         QDataStream out(&buffer);
         out << data;
         int size = buffer.size();

         if (!sharedMem.create(size)) {
             qDebug()<<"Unable to create shared memory segment."<<sharedMem.isAttached()<<" "<<sharedMem.error();

         }

         sharedMem.lock();
         char *to = (char*)sharedMem.data();
         const char *from = buffer.data().data();
         memcpy(to, from, qMin(sharedMem.size(), size));
         sharedMem.unlock();
        }
    else
        {
          qDebug()<< "no data to share"
        }

    }
```

and in main

```
SharedMemory sh;
sh.loadIntoSharedMem("memo1",data1 );
sh.loadIntoSharedMem("memo2",data2 );
sh.loadIntoSharedMem("memo3",data3 );
```

and on showSharedData.cpp in the seconde application

```
QString ShowSharedMemory::loadFromSharedMem(QString memoryKey)
{
    sharedMem.setKey(memoryKey);
    if (!sharedMem.attach())
    {
        qDebug()<<"Unable to load!";
        return"";
    }

    QBuffer buffer;
    QDataStream in(&buffer);
    QString text;

    sharedMem.lock();
    buffer.setData((char*)sharedMem.constData(), sharedMem.size());
    buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadOnly);
    in >> text;
    sharedMem.unlock();

    sharedMem.detach();
    return text;

}
```

and in main

```
data1=showMemory.loadFromSharedMem("memo1");
data2=showMemory.loadFromSharedMem("memo2");
data3=showMemory.loadFromSharedMem("memo3");
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that second write attempt overwrites all data. You need to implement cross-process containers (boost has some), like QList, if you want to share data via shared memory. It is hard topic.

I propose you to use sockets to send strings between processes. Or other platform depended mechanism (for example, pipes on windows).

Comment: No need to use platorm-dependent mechanisms. `QLocalSocket` does the trick.